# Annotate queryset with count of filtered related objects

Tags: django, django-1.8

In my django app (1.8) I have a model `TeamMember`, which has a boolean field `primary_contact` and a foreign key relationship to `User`. I would like to find the set of User objects which have no related `TeamMember` with `primary_contact=True`. (`TeamMembers` with `primary_contact=False` are fine)

I can get the count of team members easily enough:

```
User.objects.annotate(teammember__count=Count('teammember'))
```

And I can prefetch primary_contact TeamMembers easily enough as well:

```
User.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('teammember_set', queryset=.objects.filter(primary_contact=True), to_attr='primary_contacts'))
```

However, I have not found the incantation allowing me to filter a queryset by "Users who have no primary_contact team members".

Obviously, I would like to do this in the ORM, minimizing queries, and without raw SQL if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I might misunderstood your question but would this work?

```
User.objects.filter(Q(teammember__primary_contact=False) |
                    Q(teammember__isnull=True))
```

Comment: Interesting, it didn't occur to me that django's orm would allow that sort of query. That's not exactly what I was looking for, but it got me a lot closer. `User.objects.exclude(Q(teammember__primary_contact=True))`) is looking promising. Thanks!